# Unable to fetch links from website

Tags: php, html, api

Getting results like "https://bmovies.to/"a class="
but I want https://bmovies.to/movie_title?

Here is my code

```
   foreach($html->find('a[class=name]') as $head)

  {

    $head->href;

    $pre = 'https://bmovies.to/';
    $movie=$pre.$head;

    echo '<a href="'.$pre.$head.'</a>';

    $count++;

}
```

Comment: You're missing a character on your `<a>` opening tag.

Comment: Make sure to also put some text inside of your anchor tag.

Comment: please help me a little more.

Comment: Fix the issues they highlighted, then ask for more help (with specifics of what's still not working) if still needed.

Answer (score 1):

Like what @Bytewave said you're missing a character on your anchor from this line

`echo '<a href="'.$pre.$head.'</a>';`

Make a correction for your link and put some text inside of your anchor tag as below.

`echo '<a href="'.$pre.$head.'">some-text-here</a>';`

Comment: this is what i am getting <a href="https://bmovies.to/&lt;a class=" name"="" title="Jigsaw">Jigsaw (2017)</a>

Comment: the $head tag is not concatenating with $pre.,                                                i want                                                                                                            <a href="https://bmovies.to/jigsaw_link; a class=" name"="" title="Jigsaw">Jigsaw (2017)</a>

Comment: May I know what is the output when you echo the **$head** ?

Comment: <a class="name" href="/film/jigsaw.xjxp8" title="Jigsaw">Jigsaw (2017)</a>  this i got. i want the "https://www.bmovies.to/film//jigsaw.xjxp8".

Comment: Is this what you get when you `echo $head;` ?

Comment: From your reply of what you are getting, it seems like your `$head` value that it holds returning a string having **symbols like " or =** which resulting a wrong url when tried to do the combination from `echo '<a href="'.$pre.$head.'">some-text-here</a>';` . You have to make sure that your `$head` only returning a plain string to make your url work